# upload an image to amazon s3 using ajax jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am a newbie in calling rest api, I need to upload an image to amazon s3 bucket, I see there is a sample syntax as follows(took from amazon website)

> PUT /my-image.jpg HTTP/1.1
>
> Host: myBucket.s3.amazonaws.com
>
> Date: Wed, 12 Oct 2009 17:50:00 GMT
>
> Authorization: authorization string
>
> Content-Type: image/jpeg
>
> Content-Length: 11434
>
> Expect: 100-continue
>
> x-amz-storage-class: REDUCED_REDUNDANCY

How do I write this host name in the destination url in the ajax call , how do I pass the image object in this request? how do I set these details in my ajax call ?

my incomplete ajax request code which does not work

```
$.ajax({

        type: 'PUT',

        url:'https://mybucketname.s3.amazonaws.com',

        headers:{            
            'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'
        },
        success:function(data)
        {
            alert(data);
        },
        error:function(data)
        {
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        }

    });
```

Comment: you need to create a bucket on amazon to which you are uploading the file `mybucketname` should be replaced with your bucket name moreover there is [**`javascriptSDK`**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#upload-property) that you need to look into for js and make your life easier

Comment: I created a bucket on amazon, but is there any way that I could use the above details in my ajax call so that I could avoid using sdk

Comment: you have to get the [`presigned`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/browser-examples.html) url before you make an ajax call as the url you are going to use for upload and download link will be returned from the api and you need to use the javascript SDK for that

Comment: [**`THIS`**](https://gist.github.com/guumaster/9f18204aca2bd6c71a24) example can make your day i hope